# How to Derive Potential Momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, potential, potential-energy

The only derivation/definition of potential momentum I've seen is using the fact that:
$$E^2-p^2c^2=m^2c^4$$
And if you add a potential, you must subtract something else from the momentum called the potential momentum $Q$ to keep the expression on the LHS constant:
$$(E-V)^2-(p-Q)^2=m^2c^4$$
I find this to be unsatisfactory because the exact same reasoning can be applied to a Newtonian particle:
$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
$$E-\frac{p^2}{2m}=0$$
$$(E-V)-\frac{(p-Q)^2}{2m}=0$$
However, potential momentum does not have a place in Newtonian physics. Is there a better, more rigorous definition or derivation of potential momentum? And I don't understand what potential momentum even is really because it seems to only manifest in electromagnetism and literally nothing else, so I don't have an intuition on what it is.

Comment: Could it be referring to the vector potential $A$ in the potential formulation $f(\phi,A)$ of Maxwell's Eqns?

Comment: @RC_23 yes, well $Q=qA$ in the case of electromagnetism, but in general, $Q$ is the potential momentum and it's a specific four vector of the form $Q=(V/c,Q_1,Q_2,Q_3)$, and I don't understand its reasoning for existing or what $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$ are.

Comment: I've never heard of potential momentum. Can you give a reference?

Comment: @Prahar here: [link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Radically_Modern_Introductory_Physics_Text_II_(Raymond)/14%3A_Forces_in_Relativity/14.01%3A_Potential_Momentum)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help with a rigorous derivation, but perhaps a concrete example will help.

Suppose that you have a proton, mass 938.3 MeV, a neutron, mass 939.6 MeV, and a deuterium nucleus, mass 1875.6 MeV. Now, the deuteron is “composed” of a proton and a neutron, but there is a mass deficit of 2.3 MeV.

The mass deficit cannot be attributed to either the proton or the neutron, it is just an overall loss of mass for the whole nucleus. And since each proton always has the same mass and each neutron always has the same mass it would seem weird to attribute any of the mass loss to either of them anyway.

So, instead we speak of the energy of their interaction as though it were a separate entity. Note that this energy is the potential energy. That nominally separate potential energy has negative mass equal to the mass deficit.

Now, in the rest frame of the deuteron that nominal entity has a four momentum $(E/c,p_x,p_y,p_z)=(2.3,0,0,0)$ in MeV with c=1. This is the potential energy. But since energy in one frame is momentum in another we have in other frames the nominal particle’s four momentum is $(E’/c,p’_x,p’_y,p’_z)=(2.3 \gamma, 2.3\gamma v,0,0)$. In this frame there is not only a potential energy, but also a potential momentum.

Now, this is obviously not a rigorous derivation, but hopefully it gives an intuitive feel for what this potential momentum thing is and where it comes from. Also, since in Newtonian mechanics energy in one frame is not momentum in another, so it makes sense why potential momentum is not a thing that we deal with classically

Comment: Ah so I see. The Lorentz transformation basically makes the potential energy in the deuteron's rest frame bleed over into the space-like and time-like momentum in the other frame. So defining the momentum as this certain four-vector necessitates the existence of four-vector potential momentum. This gives me a good starting point, thank you.

Comment: @BilalSalha yes, that is right